# Forking system calls

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, system-calls, xv6

```
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "kernel/stat.h"
#include "user.h"
#include "kernel/fs.h"



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    int pid1 = fork();

    if (pid1 < 0 || argc < 2) {
        fprintf(2, "Fork failed.\n");
        fib(10000);
        exit();
    } else if (pid1 == 0) {
        
        
        fib(argv[1]); 
        exit();
    } else {
        int pid2 = fork();

        if (pid2 < 0) {
            fprintf(2, "Fork failed.\n");
            exit();
        } else if (pid2 == 0) {
          
            comm(pid2, argv[1]);
            exit();
        } else {
        
            wait(); 
            wait(); 

            
            for (i = 2; i < argc; i++)
                deli(atoi(argv[i]));
        }
    }

    exit(); }
```

This code is parent code that sould fork a child there is no visible errors but its simply wont even start child process

```
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "kernel/stat.h"
#include "user.h"
#include "kernel/fs.h"

void fib1(int n) {
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a);

        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp + b;
     sleep(100);
    }



    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fib1(10000);
        exit();
    }else{

        // Child process for 'fib' command
        fib1(atoi(argv[1])); // Print 'n' Fibonacci numbers
        exit();
  
    }


    exit();
}
```

This is child code sould find and print N fib numbers works fine when ran by itself.
I guess problem is somewhere in between i could provide more code but i am afraid that it will be to long of a read any advice helps.

```
struct shared child[10];
int childNum = 0;

int
fork(void)
{
    int i, pid;
    struct proc *np;
    struct proc *curproc = myproc();

    // Allocate process.
    if((np = allocproc()) == 0){
        return -1;
    }

    // Copy process state from proc.
    if((np->pgdir = copyuvm(curproc->pgdir, curproc->sz)) == 0){
        kfree(np->kstack);
        np->kstack = 0;
        np->state = UNUSED;
        
        return -1;
    }
    np->sz = curproc->sz;
    np->parent = curproc;
    *np->tf = *curproc->tf;

    // Clear %eax so that fork returns 0 in the child.
    np->tf->eax = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < NOFILE; i++)
        if(curproc->ofile[i])
            np->ofile[i] = filedup(curproc->ofile[i]);
    np->cwd = idup(curproc->cwd);

    safestrcpy(np->name, curproc->name, sizeof(curproc->name));

    pid = np->pid;

    acquire(&ptable.lock);

    np->state = RUNNABLE;

    release(&ptable.lock);

    return pid;
}
```

Above is fork function that i use

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using `strace -f` to analyze actual behavior. (Also, in general: Be sure you _actually check return codes_ and abort/print a message immediately when something goes wrong, instead of ignoring failures silently and letting more things go wrong later; `perror()` is your friend, so are return codes).

Comment: ...once you've done the work to identify where in execution something first goes wrong that contravenes your expectations, that'll put you in a good place to build a [mre] to support a clearer question.

Comment: We do need code that is complete enough to actually run.  To avoid it being too long, remove or stub out code that isn't related.  But make sure that it still builds and runs (e.g. if you remove the code for a function then also remove all calls to that function), and that the stripped-down code still exhibits the undesired behavior.  Then you will have a [mcve].